how to count traffic bytes with nf_conntrack
an arm device, not has iptables, have a bussiness process, need to count all traffic bytes of this process.
my solution:

get socket id,  ls -lh /proc/pid/fd
get port by socket id, /proc/net/tcp
get nf_conntrack info, cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack | grep port
count bytes

if my collection frequency is 1 minute, i warry some connection info will be clear by system in 1 minute, that will reduce the accuracy of collection.
what i can do to ensure the accuracy of collection? help to give some advices， thanks a lot
